# Changing column/row numbers into a character count (JavaScript)

Tags: javascript

Right now, I have two numbers, a row number and a column number for a textarea. I need to translate that to the number of characters from the beginning of the textarea.

Example:

Row 5, character 6 should translate to 108 (The cursor is right after ornare before the period) if I have:

```
Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, 
consectetur adipiscing elit. 
Suspendisse scelerisque 
sem in leo venenatis 
ornare. Aenean non
diam eget nisl 
molestie mattis.
```

Any ideas how to calculate this via JavaScript?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here you go:

```
var area = document.getElementById("txtAreaID");
var rows = area.value.split(/\n/);

var getTotal = function(row, col){
    var tot = 0;
    var i;
    for (i=0; i<(row-1); i++){
        tot+=rows[i].length;
    };
    tot+=col;
    return tot;
};

alert(getTotal(5,6));
```

Comment: your split has to be global, `/\n/g`. And that is one TERRIBLY complicated way to accomplish the

Comment: It doesn't have to be global it's a split not a search, and your answer was completely wrong. Reread the question.

Comment: you are correct, it doesn't have to be global in a split. I changed my answer. Thanks for being so gracious about it.

Answer (score 0):

```
var character_count = textarea.value.split(/\n/).slice(0,4).join('').length + 6;
```

Comment: Out of curiosity I benchmarked our answers, mine runs almost 30 times faster, although it is more verbose: http://jsperf.com/charcounting